# Limiting number of characters that an user might input is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have to limit the number of characters that an user might input in a textview. Im limiting it to 500 characters 
Following is my code,

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSInteger restrictedLength=500;

    NSString *temp=textView.text;
    NSLog(@"hekk %ld",[[textView text]length]);
    if([[textView text] length] > restrictedLength){
        textView.text=[temp substringToIndex:[temp length]-1];
    }
}
```

The problem is that, if the user edits the textview using keyboard then the user may not be able to type more than 500 characters. But if the user copy paste the texts, the user is able to input more that 500 characters. Hoe can I sort this out?

Comment: You do `substringToIndex:` only with a "-1". But indeed, if there is more than one new character (as a copy/paste), it's an issue. So why don't you do a `substringToIndex:` with a difference of length between `[[textView text] length]` and `restrictedLength`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this code in my app its work fine

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    else
    {
        if (textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length) == 400) {

            [appDel displayAlert:@"Message limit is 400 character."];
        }
        return textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length) <= 400;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use delegate method:

> shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Here a example:

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSInteger restrictedLength=500;

        NSString *temp=textView.text;
        NSLog(@"hekk %ld",[[textView text]length]);
        if(([[textView text] length] > restrictedLength)&&(range.length == 0)){
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: still the same issue exists

Comment: Are you sure this method is called?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use **shouldChangeTextInRange** delegate method for such case.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let textLenghtLimit = 100 
        let isChareactersLimitReached = (textView.text.characters.count - range.length + text.characters.count > textLenghtLimit)

        return !isChareactersLimitReached
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    int maxCharacters = 500;
    NSString *newString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    if(newString.length > maxCharacters){
        textView.text = [newString substringToIndex:maxCharacters];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method of `UITextView` Class.

Whenever text in `UITextView` changes `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` will be called.

So, you can validate your requirements in this method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    NSInteger restrictedLength=500;

    NSString *temp=textView.text;
    NSLog(@"hekk %ld",[[textView text]length]);
    if([[textView text] length] > restrictedLength){

        textView.text=[temp substringToIndex:restrictedLength];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is limiting the text entry for 100 characters

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
    {
        if(textField.text.length < 100)
        {
              return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if(range.length + range.location > textView.text.length)
    {
      return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return newLength <= 500;
 }
```